# Insert a page break in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

How can we insert a page break or force a page break in the XML using XSLT after a limit of 6 or 7 rows in a table?

I am not able to figure a way to exactly do it. the corresponding XML will be published to PDF.

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="file:///C:/Alstom/Schemas/stylermodules/AlstomCurrHTMLStyles/alstom.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<DM xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<CONTENT>
<DESCRIPT>
<PARA0>
<TITLE><EMPHASIS EMPH="BOLD">Example</EMPHASIS></TITLE>
<TABLE FRAME="ALL">
<TGROUP COLS="3">
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col1" COLWIDTH="5cm"/>
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col2" COLWIDTH="6.00cm"/>
<COLSPEC COLNAME="col3" COLWIDTH="5.91cm"/>
<THEAD>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>A</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>B</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA><EMPHASIS>C</EMPHASIS></PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
</THEAD>
<TBODY>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" MOREROWS="6" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>A1</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>B1</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>C1.</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>B2</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>C2.</PARA></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>B3</PARA></ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1"><PARA>C3</PARA><?Pub Caret -1?></ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">B4</ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">C4</ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">B5</ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">C5</ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">B6</ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">C6</ENTRY>
</ROW>
<ROW>
<?PubTbl row rht="3.08in"?>
<ENTRY COLSEP="1" ROWSEP="1">B7</ENTRY>
<ENTRY COLSEP="0" ROWSEP="1">C7</ENTRY>
</ROW>
</TBODY>
</TGROUP>
</TABLE>
</PARA0>
</DESCRIPT>
</CONTENT>
</DM>
```

For example if a page break has to be inserted after C5.

Thanks.

Comment: What is a "page break"?  The term has no meaning in XML or XSLT.  If the XML is being rendered to an output medium, whatever program is doing the rendering might have a means to insert a break but you have not told us anything about the rendering phase.

Comment: Please post the code you use to produce pdf (XSLT, ...). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear for me how you convert xml to pdf, but a way is:

```
<div style="page-break-before: always;">
```

Answer (score 1):

In XSL-FO, you can use the following code:

```
<fo:block page-break-before="always"> </fo:block>
```